# Nose wheels with camber

Tags: landing-gear, lockheed-constellation

What is the reason for the inward slanting nose wheels on a Lockheed Constellation? Are there other aircraft with same design.

Comment: I believe this question is about the camber and it has already been asked. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65376/why-are-the-constellations-nosewheels-canted-inwards

Answer (score 6):

The Connie's nose gear has the wheel axle almost on the same plane as the strut axis, so much of the castering effect is from the rake angle of the strut (like a motorcycle front fork - it's the rake angle of the fork, the slant, that makes the wheel want to caster).

[image]

This works best if the wheel pair's footprint is as narrow as possible, because when the wheel assembly with dual tires turns, the rake angle means one wheel wants to lift off the pavement a little bit (to visualize the effect, mentally take the rake angle all the way to 90 degrees and rotate the strut; one wheel lifts off the ground - go back up to 10 degrees like the Connie's nose strut; that effect, but much smaller).

Angling the wheels to get them close together at the bottom gets the narrowest possible footprint and minimizes the differential contact pressure of the tires as they rotate away from straight ahead, on a strut that is raked like that.

[image]

On most airliner nose gears with dual wheels, the strut is nearly vertical, so the steering axis is vertical, with all caster effect coming from the offset between the wheel axis and the steering axis, like a shopping cart caster. In that case the lateral wheel spacing isn't critical because the contact pressure of both tires is the same at all steering angles.

Comment: Maybe you can add [this picture](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Breitling-Super-Constellation-Flyers/Lockheed-L-1049F-Super-Constellation/2726903/L) to show what you mean.

Comment: @sophit perfect thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget the sources of the pictures.